# Hide Views from RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` which loads its data from a SQLite database. Each row has 3 `EditText`s and 1 `Checkbox`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/row_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/element_name_editText"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/element_quantity_editText"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/element_price_editText"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/element_checkBox"/>
```

This is the result:

[image: View_1]

What I am trying to achieve is to hide two views (`element_quantity_editText` and `element_price_editText`) when clicking a button in the fragment containing the `RecyclerView`. The result would be something like this

[image: View_2]

For now I tried using multiple ViewTypes as in [How to create RecyclerView with multiple view type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)

However, this only applies to the new added elements and not to the rest of them.

This is what I have now:

Myadapter

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
    mShow=mPrefs.getBoolean("0", true);

        if (viewType==VIEW_TYPE_ELEMENT){

            if(mShow) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.elements_item, parent, false);
            ElementsRowHolder vh = new ElementsRowHolder(v,mShow);
            return vh;
            }
            else{
                View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.elements_item_0, parent, false);//elements_item_0 only contains TITLE and CHECKBOX
                ElementsRowHolder vh = new ElementsRowHolder(v,mShow);
                return vh;
            }
        }
        else {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.new_element_item, parent, false);
            NewElementRowHolder vh = new NewElementRowHolder(v);
            return vh;
        }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder instanceof ElementsRowHolder) {
        ((ElementsRowHolder)holder).bindModel(mData.get(position));
        }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
        return(mData.size()+1);
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return (position == mData.size()) ? VIEW_TYPE_BUTTON : VIEW_TYPE_ELEMENT;
}
```

My ViewHolder

```
public ElementsRowHolder(View row, boolean mShow) {
    super(row);

    this.mShow = mShow;

    mElementName=(EditText)row.findViewById(R.id.element_name_editText);
    mElementQuantity=(EditText)row.findViewById(R.id.element_quantity_editText);
    mElementPrice=(EditText)row.findViewById(R.id.element_price_editText);
    mElementCheckBox=(CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.element_checkBox);

    if(mShow) {
        mElementQuantity.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mElementPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mElementName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mElementCheckBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        mElementQuantity.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mElementPrice.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mElementName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mElementCheckBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    row.setOnClickListener(this);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        row.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                v.findViewById(R.id.row_content).getBackground().setHotspot(event.getX(), event.getY());
                return(false);
            }
        });
    }
}

void bindModel(Element e) {

    mElementName.setText(e.getName());
    if (e.getQuantity() == null && e.getCost() == null) {
    } else {
        mElementQuantity.setText(e.getQuantity().toString());
        mElementPrice.setText(e.getCost().toString());
    }
    mElementCheckBox.setActivated(false);

}
```

Comment: post your code, then we can track you...

Comment: Added more code, hope it is enough!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your adapter class, make a variable

```
int var_visibility = View.VISIBLE;
```

In your ViewHolder, do following.

```
element_quantity_editText.setVisibility(var_visibility);
element_price_editText.setVisibility(var_visibility);
```

Now, in your checkbox listener do this

```
if(checkbox.isChecked)
    var_visibility = View.VISIBLE;
else
    var_visibility = View.GONE;

notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter, add a `boolean` attribute (i.e. `private boolean mShowsView`), set the true or false according to the visibility of your views.

In the `onBindViewHolder` method of your adapter, display the views only if `mShowsView` is set to "true". You can play with the

```
setVisibility(View.VISIBLE / View.GONE);
```

In your `fragment`, when you click on the button, do the following:

```
`mAdapter.setShowsView(true/false);` 
// to show or hide your views
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
// to refresh your adapter
```

Comment: This works but only for the new added elements to the Recycler View, what I am trying to achieve is to apply it to all the elements (new and old)

Comment: This method would also work for older items: just play with the visibility for every elements.
In your case, this.mShow = mShow should be called in the constructor of the adapter, not in every view binding.